# How to make some specific text bold in a paragraph in Word using openxml in C#?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am creating a Word file using OpenXml SDK in C#. Everything is working fine. I have a paragraph in which i want to make some text bold, some text underline and some without bold. But i have no idea how can i do this. I want like below:

The total amount of Bank **DHL** is **25012** according to result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Underlining and bolding text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828984/underlining-and-bolding-text)

Comment: No. This is something else. I know how to make bold and underline. But i an asking how to make some words underline and some bold.

Comment: @Umer, what's not working? please include your code in the question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You are basically saying the same thing and contrast it the next line. You should fix your explanation of the problem because that is not what you described

Comment: @AviMeltser How can i make some specific text as bold in a paragraph?

Comment: @Umer Isn't it just adding a new `Run` object? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853019/how-to-make-some-text-bold-in-cell-using-openxml